# Filtered search on database using php

Tags: php, mysql, database, filter

A table named 'books' in my database has these five attributes : State, Area, Institute, Category, Subject. I want to do a filtered search using HTML forms where a user can select up to 5 filters and submit the form to find the book from the 'books' table.

```
$sqltest="SELECT DISTINCT state FROM books order by state";
    $ex=$conn->prepare($sqltest);
    $ex->execute();
    echo "<select class='filter' name='state' onchange='showUser(this.value)'>";
    echo "<option value=' ' default selected>All State</option>";
    while($result = $ex->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "<option value='".$result["state"]."'>".$result["state"]."</option>";

    }
    echo "</select>";
```

All the other attributes get their value from the database, similarly.
I am planning on replacing the variable values with 'is not null' but I don't think it will solve the issue. Any other ways to go about it? How do I proceed?

```
if($state==" ")
        $state="is not null";

    if($institute==" ")
        $institute="is not null";

    if($location==" ")
        $location="is not null";

    if($subject==" ")
        $subject="is not null";

    if($category==" ")
        $category="is not null";
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what your question is. Is something not working, or are you just not sure what to do in general? Do you only want to select where all five variables are not null? That would imply that all of them always have data. If you only want to select based on the criteria the user selected, then not need to use not null for anything.

Comment: I am not sure what to do in general, I want to search values which are taken from 5 different select tags, the values can either be one of the options or a blank space. if the value of a an attribute is ' ', i want to return all fields and if the value is not ' ', i want to return the values selected by user.

The default dropdown value which is ' ' must return all tuples from books and the option value must return only the tuples with columnname=option value

Comment: You are going to have build a SQL statement based on the user inputs. That would define which fields you want, and the where clause that selects them. You'll have to keep track of whether you got any responses, and whether you want to 'and' or 'or' them, ( i want this stuff if this = input1 and that = input2.) It's difficult to tell still exactly what you need, as you're both talking about how to get data, and what data to return.